# Add pre-existing table to code-first migration in EF Core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I want to add a table that already exists in my SQL Server database to a `DbContext` that I have so far only used for code-first migrations using Entity Framework Core 2.0.

Is there a way for me to create a model class, add a `DbSet<T>` to the `DbContext` descendant and have it "hook-up" with the table in the database without messing future migrations if I add or modify the current model.

I would rather not have to roll-back all migrations.

Comment: Add normal migration and remove the `CreateTable` (and related) from `Up` method.

Answer (score 0):

For EF Core 2, use `scaffold` like `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ... -t Sales.Orders -t Sales.OrderLines`  See Shawn Wildermuth's article [Reverse Engineer Databases Using EF Core 2](https://wildermuth.com/2017/12/20/Reverse-Engineering-Existing-Databases-in-Entity-Framework-Core-2)

I believe you are looking for the option `-IgnoreChanges` of the EF command `Add-Migration` as detailed in Microsoft's [Entity Framework Code First Migrations with an existing database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx) (also: review the screen casts)

NOTE:  Iterating until it is perfected is done by simply deleting the last migration, or running `Remove-Migration`, making your changes, and then re-running the `Add-Migration` until you have what you want.

See also Microsoft's article [Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/)

Comment: The `-IgnoreChanges` options is unfortunately not available since I’m using EF Core.

Comment: Use `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ... -t myTable` to bring your table config from the database context as named